# Is there a way to determine if execCommand('undo') is executable? [JavaScript]

Tags: javascript, execcommand

I am trying to determine if the execCommand('undo') can be executed.

I've tried this one:

```
if(document.execCommand('undo'))
{
    document.execCommand('redo');
    // some code
}
```

and it works... But it makes me some problems with the other part of the script.

**Is there another way to see if 'undo' is executable ?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- document.queryCommandSupported
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536681(VS.85).aspx
- document.queryCommandEnabled 
  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536676(VS.85).aspx

(yes, Midas is based on IE interfaces)

Comment: Thanks! "queryCommandEnabled" works on Chrome 9 and IE7, 8, 9! Doesn't work on Firefox 3.6 and Opera 11.