# Undo and Redo in WYSYWYG contentEditable in SWT doesn't work

Tags: javascript, html, editor, swt, undo

I'm doing a WYSYWYG HTML5 editor With SWT by setting the `contentEditable` attribute of the body tag to `true`.

When I'm executing some commands like `document.execCommand('bold')`, it works perfectly. But when I try to undo an operation with `document.execCommand('undo')` nothing happens. I don't know if I have to set any undo manager or to do something like that. Can you help me please ?

Comment: Does this help
http://stackoverflow.com/a/5062713/903454

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a common problem as [Google search will reveal](https://www.google.com/search?q=document.execCommand%28%27undo%27%29). The following site has a good compatibility table and demo for testing.

- Table: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html
- Demo: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand/

They also have the following statement on the demo page:

> Undo/Redo doesn't work in IE. The problem is that the changes in the
>   textarea to the right are also added to the Undo/Redo stack. There
>   will be no textarea in the final version, so it's not necessary to
>   solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

According to [this quirksmode table](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/execCommand.html), undo/redo works in all major browsers, but it has this note:

> Undo works in Safari, but if you do Undo/Redo too often, it crashes. Solved in 3. 
>   If you make your own changes in the editable area, Undo/Redo continues to work in Mozilla and Safari (though it ignores your custom changes), but in IE and Opera it stops working.

I don't know how SWT might affect this, but it might be better to use

```
document.execCommand("undo", "", null)
```

ExecCommand has always been very buggy, and I don't know much about SWT, but I hope this helps you.