# Are there canUndo and canRedo webContents methods?

Tags: javascript, electron, chromium

I have some buttons and menu items that use undo and `redo webContents` methods; I need to enable and disable them checking if is possible `'canUndo'` and `'canRedo'`. Really I can´t find information about how to do it.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062526/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-execcommandundo-is-executable-javascript and should be closed.

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution thanks to [free-consulting](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205376/free-consulting)
at [Is there a way to determine if execCommand('undo') is executable? [JavaScript]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062526/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-execcommandundo-is-executable-javascript) solution.

```
var canUndo = document.queryCommandEnabled("undo");
```

Comment: Then vote/flag to close as a duplicate, do not post a link to someone else's answer.