# Javascript & JQuery: How to check if undo or redo available?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

So I have a `<div contenteditable>`. I implement buttons for `undo` and `redo`:

```
<button onclick="undo(event)">
<button onclick="redo(event)">

function undo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand('undo', false, null);
}

function redo(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    document.execCommand('redo', false, null);
}
```

I need to set disable for `undo` or `redo` button depending on the input history. How can I check if undo or redo available?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to determine if execCommand('undo') is executable? \[JavaScript\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5062526/is-there-a-way-to-determine-if-execcommandundo-is-executable-javascript)  **edit:** probably not as "based on input history" rather than "based on browser".  Left for reference.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this for the undo or redo status

```js
function check(){
if(document.queryCommandEnabled("undo"))
  {
    $('#undoResult').text("Undo is active");
    }else{
      $('#undoResult').text("Undo is not active");
  }
if(document.queryCommandEnabled("redo"))
  {
    $('#redoResult').text("Redo is active");
    }else{
      $('#redoResult').text("Redo is not active");
  }
  }
  $(document).on('keypress',function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13) {
        document.execCommand("insertLineBreak");
              return false;
      }
      });
  check();
```

```css
div{
  border:1px solid black;
  height:100px;
}

button{
color:white;
background:black;
height:40px;
width:49%;
padding:1px;
text-align:center;
margin-top:10px;
}

p{
font-size:30px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div contenteditable="true">
</div>

<button onclick="document.execCommand('undo',false,null);check()" >Undo</button>

<button onclick="document.execCommand('redo',false,null); check()" >Redo</button>

<p id='undoResult'></p>
<p id='redoResult'></p>
```